# Adding custom language to listings causing keyword problem

Tags: listings

I am trying to make my own syntax highlighting for ARM assembly by defining a language as follows:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{ASM}{
    morekeywords={b, ble, blt, bne, 
        ldr, str, 
        r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, rr8, r9, r10, r11, r12
        sp  },
    sensitive=false, % keywords are not case-sensitive
    morecomment=[l]{//}, % l is for line comment
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/}, % s is for start and end delimiter
    morestring=[b]" % defines that strings are enclosed in double quotes
} %
```

However when I do:

```
\lstset{language=ASM}
\begin{lstlisting}[style = ASM]
    .section .init
    .global _start

    _start:
        ldr sp, =8000
        b kernel_main
\end{lstlisting}
```

I am told "undefined control sequence ldr" and "undefined control sequence b". Removing them from the keywords solves the issue but then I have no syntax highlighting. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Rather than posting code snippets it is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that begins with as `\documentclass` command,l includes all relevant packages and `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. In this instance, it won't compile but it should be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at what you have, you seem to be missing a comma at the end of the line `...r11, r12` and your `lstlisting` environment should probably be `\begin{lstlisting}[language = ASM]`, rather than using `style`. With these two fixes your code produces:

[image]

Here is the full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{ASM}{
    morekeywords={b, ble, blt, bne,
        ldr, str,
        r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, rr8, r9, r10, r11, r12,
        sp  },
    sensitive=false, % keywords are not case-sensitive
    morecomment=[l]{//}, % l is for line comment
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/}, % s is for start and end delimiter
    morestring=[b]" % defines that strings are enclosed in double quotes
} %

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language = ASM]
    .section .init
    .global _start

    _start:
        ldr sp, =8000
        b kernel_main
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```